# Mock SPUser with my own data for unit testing

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, unit-testing

I'm using sharepoint 2013 and trying to unit testing for my methods. Had issues in methods having SPContext and HTTPContext but can resolve that with help of article [here](http://www.spdoctor.net/Pages/article.aspx?name=Unit-Testing-Supplying-SPContext)

Now i want to test the methods which are using SPUser, in order to achieve this i want to mock the user with my own data for example. I want the SPUser.LoginName as "test" and SPUser.Email as test@test.com.

My aim is to to mock the current user in unit testing i.e, web.CurrentUser

Can anyone help on this?.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Are you using any framework for mocking?

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way to Mock SPUser object. You can use various tools to perform unit testing for Sharepoint:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ff650441.aspx

http://blog.typemock.com/2008/09/16/testing-sharepoint-now-easier-with-the-new-api

http://www.telerik.com/forums/mocking-spuser

Comment: Thanks Aanchal. I tried all these already, but i'm not able to mock SPWeb.CurrentUser. instead everytime i'm gettin the user who has logged in the server, in my case its "Administrator".